# Replace words only in specific tags (regex)?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, preg-replace

By example:

I want to replace `iOS` words to `iOS 7` in an HTML string, but only in the body text, proceeded by a `<p>` tag (excluding any other cases).

I only want to replace this:

```
<p>Say hello to iOS that is contained in the body text</p>
<p>Say hello to iOS 7 that is contained in the body text</p>
```

But don't want to replace these:

```
<p>Say hello to <a href="#" alt="iOS 7 in alt text">this link.</a>
<p>Say hello to <img src="iOS 7.jpg" /> this image.
// And so on...
```

**Is it possible at all with regex?**

Comment: Possible? Maybe. Advisable? [Probably not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1557526)

Comment: @kingkero beat me to it

Comment: Wow!            Wow. Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷yOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ******

Comment: I parsed HTML with regex once... Once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use a regular expression that uses a negative lookbehind.

(?<!")iOs 7

which basically says match except those with " preceding...

...but you should really REALLY consider some kind of html parser such as BeautifulSoup which makes all of this trivial.

See here:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks. But the advises above... ...err, suggest me that I should have the content curated to have the replacee words marked by a `:iOS 7:` or something.